# Query Unbuilder class?

Tags: apex, soql

Does anyone know of query helper class like http://apex-commons.github.io/query/soql-builder/ that can deconstruct a query string?

I'm looking for an apex class that can cut up a dynamic query string into its components, to be manipulated in the way the nice, clever query builders do it, so I can use a query builder without refactoring legacy code that produces strings by concatenating. Something like "initialise the query builder by loading this string".

Comment: No help in the near future, but eventually the parser that is part of the Eclipse tooling may be made more open and the part that deals with static SOQL would probably give you the analysis that you want. See [Request to share source code to apex jorje parsing libraries](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/30).

Comment: @KeithC just added a paragraph for clarification. If the thing I want doesn't exist I might be able to build it one day based on how the jorje libs cut up static queries.